# Windows Form Listview is not visually showing selected items

Tags: windows, winforms, listview, c#-4.0

We have a tool that is being integrated into our application.  We have some strict borders around us too in that we cannot modify the application except for our extensions.  I have searched here, I've searched the internet, but cannot find any postings about this problem.

I have a Windows Form that contains a ListView and our user requires we create a checkbox to Select/Deselect all.  I have the event handler for when the check box state changes and call the routine to set everything to Selected.

```
private void SelectAllEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ChangeState(RadCapListView, SelectAllRadcap.Checked);
}

private void ChangeState(SWF.ListView control, bool state)
{
  if (control.CheckBoxes)
  {
    control.Items.OfType<SWF.ListViewItem>().ToList()
        .ForEach(item => item.Checked = state);
  }
  else
  {
    control.Items.OfType<SWF.ListViewItem>().ToList()
        .ForEach(item => item.Selected = state);
  }
  control.Refresh();
}
```

Going into debug mode all items are marked as selected.
Also at the control level SelectedItems is properly updated.

The issue is that visually the control just will not highlight the selected items like we have our WPF forms doing.  As you can see in the code I also tried to refresh the control hoping that would show items selected, but no joy.

Has anyone solved this problem in getting selected items to display properly?

Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `control.Refresh()`, try `control.Focus()`.